# Organizing functions with inter dependencies;

Tags: c++

I would like to write a set of cpp functions for importing from a file type into a data structure which has inter dependencies to each other. As I don't need any member variables to remember anything after importing the file, is it a good idea to create a class with just static functions or create a namespace and put all functions into it without class.

Comment: What is the contents of this file? What is its structure? What do you mean by "inter dependencies to each other"? What have you tried so far? What problems do you have with your code? ***What is your question?*** Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: contents and the structure of the file are not relevant to this question but just imagine you need a public function to parse a data structure from a file and this will be used by many other objects in the framework to obtain a pointer to this imported data. As you can imagine this public functions will do sub function calls (inter dependencies) to parse the data from the file. In such a case where should I place this functions? just into a namespace as c functions or into an object as static functions. What is the best practice to do?

Comment: Can you at least tell us if it's a *text* file or does it contain *binary* data? And I don't really know how you are supposed to "import" the data from the file into data structures without any member variable. And without knowing the structure of the file, it's actually impossible to say what way of "importing" the data would be "best" (which is a highly subjective matter anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do not have member variables, neither your problem defines an object then it does not make sense to create a class. A "Static class" in C++ does not exist, you are just "creating a namespace with a class". If you want to group functions then you should use namespaces.